# How to check that someone is blocked by another user in REST API

Tags: spring, rest

I am creating a REST API server for a community web application.
The user can block others in this application.
This information is stored in the database with the table named block.

What I want to implement is the API to check whether someone is blocked by another user or not.
For example, I am a user with (PK)user_id: 1 and I want to check if I am blocked by a user with user_id: 2.

In this case, what is the appropriate http form for this REST API?

```json
Request  
GET /members/1/blocks?memberId=2
  
Response  
{  
    "blocked": Boolean  
}
```

Can I do it like this? Does it still follow REST?

Comment: I think that is about right. By default you would get a full list of members blocking you and you can filter the results by adding query parameters. I would however add some extra info to the response like the user_id etc. Just bear in mind REST is not set in stone. There are some guidelines and key principles but that's about it.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle You made my day. Thanks a lot!